# How can I add a custom data attribute to each select using Rails date helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form, custom-data-attribute

I'm using simple_form with Rails' date helper.  I'm after two select drop downs for month and year.  I have the two select drop downs, but how can I apply a custom data-blah attribute for each select?

```
<%= p.input :cc_expiration, input_html: { name: nil }, discard_day: true, order: [:month, :year], prompt: true, start_year: Time.now.year, end_year: Time.now.year + 15 %>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use `f.input`, you can achieve it like this:

```
<%= f.input :year,  as: :select, input_html: { data: { blah: 'value1' } } %>
<%= f.input :month, as: :select, input_html: { data: { blah: 'value2' } } %>
```

`input_html` basically gives you the possibility to add additional html attributes and the `data` symbol lets you define special data-tags. Just pass them as a hash.

One additional note: if you just use `f.input` for a date time field, simple_form is able of  generating the 5 select boxes for year, month, day, hour, minute by itself. In this case, passing `input_html` will pass those attributes to every select box of the date/time selects.

Comment: Reading your question again I think the answer doesn't help you much since you already use date helper. It would have been easier to read if you would provide a snippet of your template. So in this case I think you have two options: 1) generate two inputs for the same field and only show one field, providing different data values, or 2) redefine the DateTimeInput and react on your attributes there.

Comment: +1 updated with a code snippet.  I'm thinking I'll go back to splitting these out into separate inputs.  I have no need to store them as a date.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I tried it now and it looks easier to use several selects than overriding the method and calling 5 times `@builder.send(:"#{input_type}_select", attribute_name, input_options, input_html_options)` with different input_html_options - and this would also lead to the fact that this is done for all datetime inputs in your app!